# Dotliquid extends error

Tags: c#, templates, extends, dotliquid

I have a very basic template ie:

```
{% extends "Body.tpl" %}

{% block content %} 
    <p>
        <a href="{{Url}}">{{Title}}</a>
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

The Body.tpl is a lot more complicated but basically has the two sections:

```
<title>{% block title %}Default Title{% endblock %}</title>
<div id="div1" class="fluid">{% block content %}No Content{% endblock %}</div>
```

and the C# code is:

```
    public static class DotLiquidTemplate
    {
        public static Template Parse( string Html )
        {
             Template.NamingConvention = new DotLiquid.NamingConventions.CSharpNamingConvention();
             Template.FileSystem = new LocalFileSystem( Globals.AbsolutePath + @"\Html\" );
             return Template.Parse( Html );
        }
    }
```

But when I try to parse the template I get the error:

```
Liquid Error - 'extends' must be the first tag in an extending template
```

But a far as I can see 'extends' is the first tag in the template.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Terry

Comment: What are you passing in to `DotLiquidTemplate.Parse`? Is it the contents of the first template - i.e. the one that starts with `{% extends ... %}`? I think I've seen that error before, when there was a Unicode byte order mark preceding the `{% extends %}` tag.

Comment: The problem is that it's picking up the Unicode BOM as the first character.